# Is it possible to get URL from inappbrowser in PWA?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, inappbrowser, embedded-browser

This example

[image: 1]

In native apps, we can control the content, get current url and run scripts inside the embedded browser.

And on iframes, we can't get / control any of the content or URLs of the iframe.

In PWAs, is it possible to get the current URL of the in app browser (like in native apps)? or get / manipulate any content in any way ?

Comment: You will not be able to manipulate the content unless the URL has the same domain as the PWA.

Comment: @Yogi Whats the way of accessing the inappbrowser of the PWA ? The same domain urls are opening in the PWA view, not in inappbrowser (as like https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUB5Q.png ), i want to know how to (if possible) access the inappbrowser of the pwa.  like read url, check if its still open / closed / navigated to another page etc.

Comment: How do you even open that in-app browser inside pwa?

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski when you click an external link in pwa, it opens as picture above.